# How to decrypt EncryptedXml in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cryptography

I'm encrypting xml document using **Cryptography.Xml** library but not able to decrypt the encrypted xml data.

Am I missing something?

**Expected result:**
should get back string xml1 and xml2 present in EncryptXmlSample() function.

[Workspace](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4x717xz886pgr6m/AACQg29TZeDZV4iWEyFWZz86a?dl=0)

**Encryption Function**

```
public string EncryptXmlSample()
    {
        try
        {
            string format = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><APlus><RequestDate>{0}</RequestDate><Login><TData version=\"{1}\"><Password>{2}</Password></TData></Login></APlus>";
            string str1 = "123456789";
            string str2 = "987654321";
            string str3 = "0.1.2.3";
            string str4 = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", (object)DateTime.Now);
            string xml1 = string.Format(format, (object)str4, (object)str3, (object)str1);
            string xml2 = string.Format(format, (object)str4, (object)str3, (object)str2);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            EncryptedXml encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml(document);
            EncryptionProvider encryptionProvider = new EncryptionProvider("key container");

            encryptionProvider.Persist();
            RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = encryptionProvider.Provider;
            if (provider == null)
                return null;
            encryptedXml.AddKeyNameMapping("ASeed", (object)provider);
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(provider.ExportCspBlob(false));

            document.LoadXml(xml1);
            string str5 = "AData";
            EncryptedData encryptedData1 = encryptedXml.Encrypt(document["APlus"], "ASeed");

            encryptedData1.Type = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element";
            encryptedData1.Id = str5;
            DataReference dataReference1 = new DataReference();
            dataReference1.Uri = "#" + str5;
            DataReference dataReference2 = dataReference1;
            IEnumerator enumerator1 = encryptedData1.KeyInfo.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator1.MoveNext();
            ((KeyInfoEncryptedKey)enumerator1.Current).EncryptedKey.AddReference(dataReference2);
            string str6 = encryptedData1.GetXml().OuterXml.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
            //string str6 = encryptedData1.GetXml().OuterXml;

            document.LoadXml(xml2);
            EncryptedData encryptedData2 = encryptedXml.Encrypt(document["APlus"], "ASeed");
            IEnumerator enumerator2 = encryptedData2.KeyInfo.GetEnumerator();
            enumerator2.MoveNext();
            ((KeyInfoEncryptedKey)enumerator2.Current).EncryptedKey.AddReference(dataReference2);
            string str7 = "&lt;?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?&gt;" + encryptedData2.GetXml().OuterXml.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;");
            //string str7 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>" + encryptedData2.GetXml().OuterXml;

            return (
                "<Settings><ReleaseId>New</ReleaseId><Seed>"
                + base64String
                + "</Seed><ADatabases><ADatabase><DatabaseType xmlns=\"http://sample.com/AuthService\">after</DatabaseType><APlusPassword xmlns=\"http://sample.com/AuthService\">"
                + str6
                + "</APlusPassword></ADatabase><ADatabase><DatabaseType xmlns=\"http://sample.com/AuthService\">before</DatabaseType><APlusPassword xmlns=\"http://sample.com/AuthService\">"
                + str7
                + "</APlusPassword></ADatabase></ADatabases></Settings>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Test Code**: Which is used for test the code

```
void testCode()
    {
        SetText("");

        string encryptedXml = EncryptXmlSample();
        AppendText("Encrypted", encryptedXml);

        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.LoadXml(encryptedXml);
        EncryptedXml encryptedXml1 = new EncryptedXml(document);

        Encryptor encryptor = new Encryptor("key container");

        encryptor.Persist();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = encryptor.Provider;

        string dec = encryptor.Decrypt(encryptedXml);
        AppendText("Decrypted", dec);
    }
```

**EncryptionProvider**: method for encrypt and decrypt using RSACryptoServiceProvider

```
public class Encryptor
{
    private static object syncObject = new object();
    internal static string KeyContainerName = "key container";
    internal RSACryptoServiceProvider provider;
    internal const int KeyBitLength = 1024;
    private const bool UsePkcsV15Padding = true;
    private const string KeyName = "ASeed";

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            return this.Provider.Encrypt(data, false);
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    public string Decrypt(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(xml);
            EncryptedXml encryptedXml = new EncryptedXml(document);
            encryptedXml.AddKeyNameMapping("ASeed", (object)this.Provider);
            encryptedXml.DecryptDocument();
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            document.Save((TextWriter)stringWriter);
            return stringWriter.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            
        }
    }

    public void Persist()
    {
        try
        {
            Encryptor.SaveContainedProvider().ImportCspBlob(this.GetKeyAsBlob());
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }

    public RSACryptoServiceProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            bool flag = false;
            try
            {
                if (this.provider == null)
                    this.provider = Encryptor.FindContainedProvider();
                return this.provider;
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public void SetKeyBlob(byte[] blob) => this.provider.ImportCspBlob(blob);
    private byte[] GetKeyAsBlob() => this.Provider.ExportCspBlob(true);
    internal byte[] GetPublicKeyAsBlob() => this.Provider.ExportCspBlob(false);

    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider CreateProvider()
    {
        return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
    }

    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider FindContainedProvider() => Encryptor.FindContainedProvider(false) ?? Encryptor.CreateProvider();

    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider FindContainedProvider(bool flag)
    {
        CspParameters parameters = new CspParameters()
        {
            KeyContainerName = Encryptor.KeyContainerName,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseExistingKey
        };
        
        try
        {
            return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, parameters);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return (RSACryptoServiceProvider)null;
    }

    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider SaveContainedProvider()
    {
        CspProviderFlags cspProviderFlags = CspProviderFlags.NoFlags;
        return new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, new CspParameters()
        {
            KeyContainerName = Encryptor.KeyContainerName,
            Flags = cspProviderFlags
        });
    }

    public Encryptor(string keyContainerName) => Encryptor.KeyContainerName = keyContainerName;
}
```

**Output:**

Encrypted:

```
<Settings>
<ReleaseId>New</ReleaseId>
<Seed>
    BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQBxvmtQqvF6wA8K748AeooubmE6Ip3Yir0r9TrzdsWZ4LvmBOhcSLVaEjncBRU7AH/sVTz/J/zw9mIDgWZ2/sMPpbmpKJxGAvrg31H9GynW0QhANMqqPcDk2xkKeENLFfqZX1XpvzgQZmO8DYx13lCRNzNegH1USZM3lF6igJTOog==
</Seed>
<ADatabases>
    <ADatabase>
        <DatabaseType xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">after</DatabaseType>
        <APlusPassword xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">&lt;EncryptedData Id="AData"
            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;KeyName&gt;ASeed&lt;/KeyName&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;Knq1Y5DYc4rE5iqZwI5yX9hzCxkDRq4QOp4eaPDgBN+6Ev791iXxZFOrBjb3f1oqKV7AJgoiudfTXTNKlpwN8B0pHUe+xGmuMj6h3A3P4jqFwPDCubfgYlFAQ69EjB0hBm4JO4UQ4o1W48KCbR+cXyJOxO9HDwebsJeAsZ7j2kk=&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;ReferenceList&gt;&lt;DataReference
            URI="#AData" /&gt;&lt;/ReferenceList&gt;&lt;/EncryptedKey&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;qZe6bZk8AKNqIWLuhkpcQaU7V6uvaWDu7/WVT/vgiv3Y5Ns6LjW2lBtMjX/6mX5oKL7hIQvlDLWgWuXZ8vniYwbzFBkVfEPSR335Hhjd5Y2DGgSCFdq21jfQsZiMzsZSk3DV6pV/WjnqnHzf3QgPQSx0iFycGy2FLrf1CMJ0QCQCTV6Ey9m8Vn9tUHaqxLEaimlIvmU+mUEU5DJpLYzWZw==&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;/EncryptedData&gt;
        </APlusPassword>
    </ADatabase>
    <ADatabase>
        <DatabaseType xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">before</DatabaseType>
        <APlusPassword xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;EncryptedData
            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;KeyName&gt;ASeed&lt;/KeyName&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;YVi3Ks13f26nAgzUwljEcaA3ItL+xvdFwDOPO9DEC0hCT+oOadfG3vuQDQ0wVBdmKCR7EbmJ0dRpeEwaRW/xrtoJwLZfnnf8SCSFqKwxRPUAg2Nn23ckBCy8st7yvgfoCmUVZi6d8C1kodNcTtgOCWiDrmujZ0mSgzPo5sW2uUg=&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;ReferenceList&gt;&lt;DataReference
            URI="#AData" /&gt;&lt;/ReferenceList&gt;&lt;/EncryptedKey&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;Xn9Jp1m+3Qhjj57sbZSLtebkoLELWYAAlRchGpGHNnZ0waWMLaXvH/vC8oJw1n0hyh7Z/e7er7UvyCi6TySrBYhP83Icys+mZ9cQ1np29Il2aEqa76FUjZwFuoNu6Bpos4aoVB6JbhMcTx5J4F45iXMAF+n1Uia7Bsgex7DxHIw31R3KxHbUu3BTto3TaRF3fPAX6Mz5RNlLIPcSWLprdA==&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;/EncryptedData&gt;
        </APlusPassword>
    </ADatabase>
</ADatabases>
</Settings>
```

Decrypted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Settings>
<ReleaseId>New</ReleaseId>
<Seed>BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAQAAAEAAQBxvmtQqvF6wA8K748AeooubmE6Ip3Yir0r9TrzdsWZ4LvmBOhcSLVaEjncBRU7AH/sVTz/J/zw9mIDgWZ2/sMPpbmpKJxGAvrg31H9GynW0QhANMqqPcDk2xkKeENLFfqZX1XpvzgQZmO8DYx13lCRNzNegH1USZM3lF6igJTOog==</Seed>
<ADatabases>
    <ADatabase>
        <DatabaseType xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">after</DatabaseType>
        <APlusPassword xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">&lt;EncryptedData Id="AData" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;KeyName&gt;ASeed&lt;/KeyName&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;Knq1Y5DYc4rE5iqZwI5yX9hzCxkDRq4QOp4eaPDgBN+6Ev791iXxZFOrBjb3f1oqKV7AJgoiudfTXTNKlpwN8B0pHUe+xGmuMj6h3A3P4jqFwPDCubfgYlFAQ69EjB0hBm4JO4UQ4o1W48KCbR+cXyJOxO9HDwebsJeAsZ7j2kk=&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;ReferenceList&gt;&lt;DataReference URI="#AData" /&gt;&lt;/ReferenceList&gt;&lt;/EncryptedKey&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;qZe6bZk8AKNqIWLuhkpcQaU7V6uvaWDu7/WVT/vgiv3Y5Ns6LjW2lBtMjX/6mX5oKL7hIQvlDLWgWuXZ8vniYwbzFBkVfEPSR335Hhjd5Y2DGgSCFdq21jfQsZiMzsZSk3DV6pV/WjnqnHzf3QgPQSx0iFycGy2FLrf1CMJ0QCQCTV6Ey9m8Vn9tUHaqxLEaimlIvmU+mUEU5DJpLYzWZw==&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;/EncryptedData&gt;</APlusPassword>
    </ADatabase>
    <ADatabase>
        <DatabaseType xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">before</DatabaseType>
        <APlusPassword xmlns="http://sample.com/AuthService">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"&gt;&lt;EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" /&gt;&lt;KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"&gt;&lt;KeyName&gt;ASeed&lt;/KeyName&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;YVi3Ks13f26nAgzUwljEcaA3ItL+xvdFwDOPO9DEC0hCT+oOadfG3vuQDQ0wVBdmKCR7EbmJ0dRpeEwaRW/xrtoJwLZfnnf8SCSFqKwxRPUAg2Nn23ckBCy8st7yvgfoCmUVZi6d8C1kodNcTtgOCWiDrmujZ0mSgzPo5sW2uUg=&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;ReferenceList&gt;&lt;DataReference URI="#AData" /&gt;&lt;/ReferenceList&gt;&lt;/EncryptedKey&gt;&lt;/KeyInfo&gt;&lt;CipherData&gt;&lt;CipherValue&gt;Xn9Jp1m+3Qhjj57sbZSLtebkoLELWYAAlRchGpGHNnZ0waWMLaXvH/vC8oJw1n0hyh7Z/e7er7UvyCi6TySrBYhP83Icys+mZ9cQ1np29Il2aEqa76FUjZwFuoNu6Bpos4aoVB6JbhMcTx5J4F45iXMAF+n1Uia7Bsgex7DxHIw31R3KxHbUu3BTto3TaRF3fPAX6Mz5RNlLIPcSWLprdA==&lt;/CipherValue&gt;&lt;/CipherData&gt;&lt;/EncryptedData&gt;</APlusPassword>
    </ADatabase>
</ADatabases>
</Settings>
```

Comment: Encryption/Decryption should work for any string and should not matter on the type of string.  So get the Encrypt/Decrpt code working and the rest should automatically work.  so your decrypt method should not be using a XmlDocument. It should just decrypt the input string.

Comment: Using an 1024 sized RSA key you can encrypt (only) a little more than 100 bytes of data (here: xml-data) - you should think about an **hybrid encryption** or **aes encryption solo**

Comment: It's some kind of weird form of XMLenc, but I see too much voodoo going on to spot what is really being done.

Comment: @MichaelFehr How to decrypt ? As I know in RSA has public and private key, public key is only do encrypt part and for decryption you need private key. Here I don't know exact way to decrypt the data. In workspace output you can see the data on text view

Comment: As @Maarten Bodewes commented there is to much weird XMLenc'ing and I'm not been able to write an decrypt function. The main problem with the plaintext size remains and as XML-data has a lot of overhead with the tags you will easy hit the limit.

Comment: @MichaelFehr This is not the case here whole XML is not encrypted. EncryptedXML is only encrypt the elements. Output is added in question

Comment: @MichaelFehr In other words, XML-enc is implicitly hybrid from the XML API, but explicitly hybrid if you look at the encrypted XML (i.e. the `EncryptionMethod` specifies the AES mode).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If you see Encryption code I'm storing Seed value i.e CspBlob but not able to decrypt the data correctly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, but I simply don't have enough knowledge about the framework to see this easily. The code is also rather convoluted, but I might be able to miss the issue even if it has been written clearly. So I cannot readily answer (and time is unfortunately limited).